# How to generate WPF Form using T4?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, dynamic

One of our product requirement is to allow the generation of Search form. So we need to facilitate the user to generate the search form based on the selected data fields.

Now our application is in WPF. Can anybody guide me how to start this thing. I have been told to research on T4, But any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, its T4, not T1.....

Comment: Note you can edit your question to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually T4 won't help you much here I'm afraid; T4 generates code in the IDE (Visual Studio), before compiling and shipping to a customer.

You'll need to look into generating the controls dynamically, most likely through data binding and MVVM as it's cleanest.

Comment: Thanks Alex and everybody else. I think this is a deep topic I need to discuss with my management again.

Comment: Is it possible to generate .xaml and .xaml.cs files using template T4 and generate different screens using a .xml file from T4 ?

Comment: While it's certainly possible, I can't clearly grasp the scenario where it would really make sense. Even if you would want a multitude of forms generated based on some inputs, I'd say it's much easier and flexible to rely on WPF mechanisms and keep the separate types to a minimum. But if it really suits your scenario, sure. Simply add a new T4 template and from there on you can get some inspiration from the entity framework T4 lib (ex. EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude) and build on that. You'll want to write code to set the build action for the resulting XAML file to 'Page' and stuff like that.